# alias mysql in .bashrc not working after login/reboot

Tags: linux, debian

After running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` this doesn't work anymore

When I type `mysql` in the command line this error is returned

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

If I run this it works until next login

```
alias mysql=/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin/mysql
echo "alias mysql=/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin/mysql" >> /root/.bashrc
```

I'm logging in via putty as `root`

## /root/.bashrc

```
alias mysql=/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin/mysql
```

## /root/.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n
```

## /root/.bash_profile

```
#############################################################################

export PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;36m\]\h \[\033[01;33m\]\w \[\033[01;35m\]\$ \[\033[00m\]'
umask 022

#############################################################################

eval "`dircolors`"

#############################################################################

alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias s='ssh -l root'

#############################################################################

export EDITOR="vim"

export HISTFILESIZE=99999999
export HISTSIZE=99999999
export HISTCONTROL="ignoreboth"

export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto -h'

#############################################################################
```

After adding the alias in the command line you can run `mysql` but if you run a shell script the script returns the same error

```
restore.sh: 315: restore.sh: mysql: not found
```

## update

```
# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Is the `~/profile` file in `/root` or in your normal user's home directory?

Comment: It is root profile :)

Comment: OK, so how do you log in? Do either `/root/.bash_profile` or `/root/.bash_login` exist? Is root's shell `bash`?

Comment: Aliases are normally only used by interactive shells, not scripts. So even if you solve the login problem, that won't fix `restore.sh`. You should solve this problem by putting the command in your PATH, not with aliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few possible problems here.

1. You are not running as `root`. The alias is defined in root's `~/.bashrc` so if you are running as another user, it will not be found. If this is the case, add the `alias` line to you user's `~/.bashrc` or switch to root.
2. You are running as root but you're not running `bash`. Log in as root and check the output of `echo $SHELL`. If that is not `/bin/bash`, use the `chsh` command to set it to bash.
3. You are running as `root` but this is a login shell (for example if you've used `ssh` to log in). If the `~/profile` you show is not in `/root`, then the `.bashrc` alias will not be loaded. Login shells ignore `.bashrc` which is why you have those lines in your `.profile`.

   If the `.profile` is root's, it could still be ignored if either `/root/.bash_profile` or `/root/bash_login` exist.

---

#### UPDATE

Now that you have given more information, I can tell you that the problem is actually 3. So, you're connecting over ssh which means that you are running [a login shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479/85695). These shells don't read `.bashrc` which is why your `.profile` contains the little loop that calls `.bashrc` explicitly.  However, if either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exists, `~/.profile` is ignored. So, because you also have `~/.bash_profile`, ~/.profile`is not read and since`~/.bash_profile`does not source`~/.bashrc`, your alias is not available. This is explained in`man bash`:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-inter‐    active shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes  com‐    mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file
>   exists.  After reading    that file, **it looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in  that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.**
>   The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the    shell is started to
>   inhibit this behavior.

So, the simplest solution would be to merge the files. Either add the lines from `.profile` to `.bash_profile` or *vice versa*. If you choose to add the lines from `~/.bash_profile` to ~/.profile`, make sure you delete`~/.bash_profile` after merging.

---

Whatever the reason, the alias will never be available to your scripts. When running a script, bash is invoked as a non-interactive, non-login shell and both `~/.profile` and `.bashrc` are ignored. Additionally, aliases are not made available to scripts unless you activate the `expand_aliases` option:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

So, to make an alias work in your script you will need to i) manually read the file where that alias is defined (because `~/.bashrc` is not read by scripts) and ii) enable the `expand_aliases` option.

For example:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

## Make your aliases available to the script
shopt -s expand_aliases

## Read .bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

## Run your mysql command
mysql
```

Comment: It used to work.. But I think after running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrad` the aliases don't work anymore

Comment: @clarkk the details will depend on exactly how you're logging in. So, please [edit] your question and tell us i) which user you are running this as ii) whose .profile you show iii) whether any of the files I mentioned in my 3d point exist iv) confirm that you're actually running bash and not `/bin/sh` which is the default shell for root AFAIK.

Comment: have updated the question.. i'm running `/bin/bash` and i'm logged in as `root`

Comment: @clarkk please answer all my questions. Also, how are you logging in? Is this a graphical system? Are you logging in from the command line? Are you using ssh? These all can change the behavior of your shell. Also try running `bash` after you log in. That should read `~/.bashrc`. If that works, let me know.

Comment: Is logging ind via putty (ssh).. what do you mean by running `bash`? When typing `bash` the console changes to a gray font

Comment: Argh! OK, you're logging in via putty. That's the kind of thing we need to know. Please [edit] and add this to your question. Now, I think there is a setting in putty that controls what kind of shell you launch, so check that. Running `bash` after logging in will start an interactive, non-login shell which should read your .bashrc automatically. Is `mysql` there after running `bash`? If not, there's a problem with your `.bashrc`. Also, I ask again, do either `/root/.bash_login` or `/root/.bash_profile` exist? Finally, just to be 100% sure you're running bash, post the output of `ps --pid $$`.

Comment: Where to I check the settings in putty when I open the terminal through winscp? But before `apt-get upgrade` it worked without starting `bash` first :( Yes, `mysql` works when running in `bash-mode`.. `/root/.bash_login` does not exit but `/root/.bash_profile` does.. Have updated the question with the content of the file

Comment: When running the `restore.sh` script from `bash` then `mysql` is still not found

Comment: @clarkk see updated answer. Your `.profile` is not being read because `.bash_profile` exists and aliases are not available to scripts buy default.

Comment: Ok, but what had happened since scripts worked with aliases before `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @clarkk they didn't, sorry. Either you had it defined as a function, not an alias or there was a link to the `mysql` binary somewhere in your path. No bash script would work with aliases without the two lines I show in my answer. The only other possibility would be that you had set the `$BASH_ENV` variable to point to your a file that contained both the alias and enabled `expand_aliases` (see the INVOCATION section of `man bash`).

Comment: Ok, but how do I then make aliases work in the command line (how to load `/root/.bashrc` on login).. But I'm still 100% sure alias worked before `apt-get upgrade` in shell scripts.. Have not changed anything except upgrading :)

Comment: @clarkk as I said in my answer, you need to "Either add the lines from .profile to .bash_profile or vice versa.". Alternatively, just delete `.bash_profile`. Your `.profile` reads `.bashrc` so you need to make sure that `.profile` is being read. To do that, you need to delete `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add mysql's bin to your system's $PATH. You can see which locations are in your $PATH variable by type `echo $PATH`. Programs in these locations are launchable by simply typing their name.

There is a section in the mysql docs about installing from binary that addresses adding mysql to your system's $PATH variable. The relevant text is:

```
**Update environment var /etc/profile    
    nano /etc/profile        
    export MYSQL_HOME=/opt/mysql/server-5.6        
    export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL_HOME/bin        
    export MANPATH=$MANPATH:$MYSQL_HOME/man
```

You can read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-installation.html